# features of segmented regions of the approximation matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, wavelet, regions

I'm using multiresolution approach for segmentation based on wavelet transform and watershed algorithm. To merge the over-segmented regions, i need to calculate the features of each segmented region of the approximation matrix (such as the mean,second and third order central moments). My problem is i don't know how to define each region separately. In other words, i don't success writing these equations with matlab.

[image]

Comment: Your question is ill-posed.  How exactly are you segmenting the regions?  Where is your code for that?  Those equations don't really mean much to me as they're simply quantitative measures.  How do you use those to define a region?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi rayryeng ,thank you for your answer. 
Well i used watershed algorithm to segment my image. The result of this algorithm is a labelled matrix that defines the regions. I want to calculate these features for each region (as you can see in the equations " Ri(x,y)").